# GitHub API - associating Releases/Tags with Milestones/Issues

Tags: github-api

Using the GitHub API, one can link Releases and Tags using `release.tag_name = tag.name`, and one can link Issues and Milestones using `issue.milestone.id = milestone.id`.

From what I can tell these two pairs seem to be independent. Is there a way to link Releases or Tags with Issues or Milestones?